# Show that the function $\cos(x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \Bigl(\prod_{l=1}^{k}\frac{2l}{2l+1}\Bigr)\sin^{2k+1}(x)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, power-series, spherical-coordinates

Can you **prove** or **disprove** the following?

The periodic function $f:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
f(x):=\cos(x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigg(\prod_{l=1}^{k}\frac{2l}{2l+1}\bigg)\sin^{2k+1}(x)
\end{align*}
is continuous and attains therefore its maximum on the interval $[0,2\pi]$.
Just to make notation clear: The empty product $\prod_{l=1}^0$ is set to 1.

For $x\ne\frac{\pi}{2}$, $f$ is continuous because the sum converges. This follows since the geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin^k(x)$ converges. We have to show continuity for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

EDIT 2:

We claim that it is possible to show that
\begin{align*}
\cos(x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigg(\prod_{l=1}^{k}\frac{2l}{2l+1}\bigg) \sin^{2k+1}(x)\leq \cos(x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{\sin^{2k+1}(x)}{\sqrt{2k+1}}=:g(x).
\end{align*}
Hence, it is left to prove that $g(x)$ is contiuous in $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

It is known that the function 
\begin{align*}
\cos(x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin^k(x)=\begin{cases}
   \frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)} & \text{for }\quad x\ne \frac{\pi}{2}\\
  0      & \text{for }\quad x= \frac{\pi}{2}
 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
is **not** continous.

Notice, in EDIT 1, there was a mistake. It should be but the square root as it is now, not the k-root.

Comment: EDIT: It is sufficient to show the function is continuous in $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the Cauchy product helps. Define
$$
h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigg(\prod_{l=1}^{k}\frac{2l}{2l+1}\bigg)\sin^{2k+1}(x)
$$
and
$$
\cos(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}
$$
Then,
$$
\cos(x)h(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k $$
where $ c_k=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i b_{k-i}$.

We calculate $c_k$ in this case
$$
c_k=\sin^{2k+1}(x)\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i\frac{x^{2i}}{\sin^{2i}(x)}\frac{1}{(2i)!}\bigg(\prod_{l=1}^{k-i}\frac{2l}{2l+1}\bigg).
$$
The hardest problem is now to show the convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k$.

Since is it known that $\cos(x)h(x)$ is continous for $x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, it is sufficient to show that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k$ converges for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: This seems to be a nasty calculation

Comment: Maybe $\lim_{x\to o}\frac{sin(x)}{x}=1$ helps